# Android - Using Id from phpmysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

I made a register in Android. One of components in register layout is spinner. The spinner contains the house number. when the user chooses the spinner it will become the user's id. I uses the MySQL. how do I connect the id's spinner with mysql? and the id will forever belong to the user.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: try to use some code in your question specificly

Answer (score 0):

following link will help you. the server side application doesn't matter. it's up to you to write your own server side application which provide you with required JSON object. I think the client code is what you are looking for. feel free to ask any other questions.

https://www.androidhive.info/2013/12/android-populating-spinner-data-from-mysql-database/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the link you provided is very helpful.